# Serializing errors to JSON in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, error-handling

I’ve been trying to find and an easy way to serialize all of the errors to JSON in Rails 6. Not writing the custom ones, but just add a standard JSON format for them. Wrote a serializer like:

```
class ErrorSerializer

def initialize(error)
@error = error
end

def to_h
serializable_hash
end

def to_json(_payload=nil)
to_h.to_json
end

private

def serializable_hash
{
errors: [error.serializable_hash].flatten
}
end

attr_reader :error
end
```

And in my User controller, tried to render error with:

```
render json: ErrorSerializer.new(@user.errors.to_hash), status: :bad_request
```

But getting an error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `serializable_hash')
```

Has anyone encountered something similar? And, in general, what is the best/easiest way to serialize all errors to JSON in Rails 6 (ideally, if there won’t be a need to raise/render errors on each endpoint in the controller)

Comment: The problem is that you're calling `error.serializable_hash`. Hashes don't have a `serializable_hash` method so its very unclear how you would expect this to work or what you actually want to get in terms of output. The whole thing would be much more flexible and useful if you took the model instance as input instead of just a hash.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs some simple errors serializer. This worked fine for me:

```
class ActiveRecordErrorsSerializer
  attr_reader :object

  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
  end

  def to_h
    serializable_hash
  end

  def as_json(_payload = nil)
    { data: { type: 'errors' }, attributes: to_h }
  end

  private

  def serializable_hash
    object.errors.messages.flat_map do |field, errors|
      errors.flat_map do |error_message|
        {
          source: { pointer: "/data/attributes/#{field}" },
          details: error_message
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```